# Banach chicken story

Tags: functional-analysis, banach

I think in undergrad functional analysis we were told an anecdote that at Stefan Banach's university in Warsaw they maintained a list of open problems which had material prizes attached to them including chickens. But I can't find anything on that with google.

Does somebody have a reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be referencing the [Scottish Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Book), and specifically problem 153 (whether all Banach spaces have the [approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property)), for the solution of which Mazur promised a live goose as prize. Said prize was later awarded to Per Enflo in 1972 for proving the claim false.

**Added:** A complete pdf version of the Scottish Book, translated in English and with some commentary by Ulam is available at

https://web.archive.org/web/20180428090844/http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/ks-szkocka/ks-szkocka3ang.pdf

It also contains the original formulation of problem 153, which is not exactly the same as the one I had previously mentioned (though with a little effort I reckon that it's possible to reconstruct why they are considered equivalent).

**Added (2):** Following the comments by Gerald Edgar and Margaret Friedland, a piece of information that's worth mentioning here is that the Scottish Book was written while Banach was working in Lwów (today's L'viv, in Ukrainian). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Banach) doesn't mention Banach ever being associated with Warsaw-based cultural instituitons: he was working in Lwów essentially all the time that international contingencies allowed it, and sometimes he was in Kraków.

Comment: And furhermore, the *Scottish Book* was kept at the Scottish Cafe, which was not in Warsaw, but in the Polish city of Lwów.  Recently, Lwow has been in the news: Now part of Ukraine, its Ukranian name is Lviv.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, Banach spent all his professional life in Lwów. He was never affiliated with any academic institution in Warsaw.

Comment: I think _redacted_ would be better _published_. At least in most dialects of English it means to blank out or remove from the text, often to preserve someone's privacy.